# how to write conditional statements inside div html?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-5.4

I have a requirement of showing 2 div's based on a condition like if value is '1' show one div else if value is '0' display another div. Below is my code:

```
<div class="csv" <?php if($campaign[0]->method != 'CSV'){ echo "style='display:none'"; } ?> >
 -----------
 ------------
</div>

<div class="api" <?php if($campaign[0]->method != 'API'){ echo "style='display:none'"; } ?> >
 ----------
 ----------
</div>
```

Code is looking fine but not working properly. I am trying to achieve this in Laravel 5.4 framework. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors or the logic is not working properly ?

Comment: What does "not working properly" mean? Do you get the correct HTML when looking at view-source?

Comment: Any information would be appreciated. What do you get with vardump($campaign);

Comment: do you want to show/hide your div elements using CSS or completely print only the div's based on the conditions?

Answer (score 2):

you can do inline if statements like this:

```
<div class="csv" <?php echo ($campaign[0]->method != 'CSV' ? 'style="display: none;" : ''); ?>></div>

() - starts the if statement and closes
?  - is the if condition is met
:  - is the else
```

Comment: Isn't that almost exactly what he is already doing - without wasting a ternary.

Comment: wating a ternary :o if anything a ternary is used to stop extra use of chars for an if statement haha xD but in some way yes, but I know 100% that the format for if statements in divs should be the above. if a var_dump of `$campaign[0]->method` returns something unexpected, it's not the code/if statement - it's the method

Comment: There IS no else, so yes, wasting. If his posted code does not work then neither will yours

Comment: it isn't a waste if it reduces characters - thus reducing the size of the file. regardless of else being null. If that will be the case then the whole question should be removed and redone with a new title about the method.

Comment: Your statement is 3 chars longer than his - he does not need the if

Comment: @mplungjan well in this case it adds 4 characters hahah but its still 100% cleaner than a straight up if statement - so much easier to read and manage

Comment: ??? A ternary is easier to read and manage than a single if? What have you been smoking today?

Comment: @mplungjan really? You're telling me that a single if looks nicer? it looks so messy :/ but before you carry on trying to insult - it is down to preference, to most people I've met and know, ternary is a lot easier.. maybe you're the one that's been smoking .. if so .. share ;) <3

Comment: you're missing a ' character in the code you posted. I can't edit your answer because it isn't "at least 6 characters"

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to drop into and out of the PHP processor which will allow you to put the logic into the html file. The following also uses [PHP Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

I removed the `style="display: none";` bits as I assume that was included to hide the alternate `<div>`.

```
<?php //drop into PHP processor mode
if($campaign[0]->method != 'CSV'): //now, back to html processing mode ?>
    <div class="csv">
        <!-- html markup-->
    </div>
<?php elseif($campaign[0]->method != 'API'): ?>
    <div class="api">
        <!-- html markup-->
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use short form of if statement, and write it inside of curly braces as laravel blades' echo.

```
<div class="api" {{ $campaign[0]->method != 'API' ? "style='display:none'" : "" }}>
```

It may help you

Comment: are you using blade template engine ?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact response to your answer, but you need to have in mind that doing display: none you can always show it playing with the css a bit. In order to prevent that, you should use conditional in php to only render what you desire to show, to prevent the code to be visible. I'd do this way:

```
<?php if($campaign[0] == 'CSV'):?>

    <div class="csv">
     -----------
     ------------
    </div>

<?php elseif($campaign[0] == 'API'):?>

    <div class="api">
     ----------
     ----------
    </div>

<?endif;
```

Or using a switch if there are more options than CSV and API